# Real-time progress bar on windows batch

Tags: command-line, batch, encryption

Well, i'm very new for batch stuff.. i'm still learning while i'm writing a decryption batch.
anyways, i want to make a progress bar while the command is processing but it seems impossible (at least for me).
this my code :

```
echo [41m The Password Is : wave4tech[0m
echo.
echo  Please Enter The Password :
rem **all dlls or modules are in sub folder named data just to make everything clear
cd "data" 
'some decryption commands' wave4tech.net >nul 2>&1 && echo Your Files Decrypted Successfully || echo [101;93m You Entered Wrong Password, Please Try Again![0m
7z x %UserProfile%\Desktop\archive -o"%UserProfile%\Desktop\" >nul 2>&1
del "%UserProfile%\Desktop\archive" >nul 2>&1
pause
```

everything is working as expected! the only problem is that after user enters the password it takes a lot of time to decrypt files so the user may close the batch, i just want to inform him about an action is happening even if its simple animated dots like (......) but if it is real time it will be better (not just random timed animations so it keeps animating for addition minutes even after process is done).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend doing this in powershell, as powershell has support for drawing progress bars. Keep in mind that it is still going to be a 0%, 50%, 100% bar where you can set it to 0% at the start of the script, then 10% before decrypting, etc... but that it will appear stuck at 10% still. Unless you have more control over the decrypting process, its hard to make the progressbar do more.

Comment: sir forget about the progressbar -- what about a message telling the user (please wait) while the decrypting is processing? is there an statement like (while echo please wait...)

Comment: Yes, `echo Please wait, may take a while.` xD But seriously, it may be better to just show 7z's progress to the user, and not redirect its output to nul.

Comment: Hmm looks like you didn't understand me.. i know that i can just write (echo please wait...) but i want to show it directly after user enters the password and while decryption progress is processing i want it show to the use (please wait it might take some minutes) and want it disappear after the process is done.. i mean if progress bar is hard, i want at least something like that.. so to be alittle more cleare; when user enters the password it will directly show a n echo to the user says (please wait..) and then disappears. About (null) redirection i want interface as clean,simple as possible

Comment: a batch file is executed in order of operation, where an enter is executing that line. You can use `cls` to clear the screen, so after the user enters their password, you can type `cls` followed by `echo please wait` and after the pgp command finishes, you can `echo please wait some more...` and after the 7-zip command finishes, you can type `cls` followed by `echo we're done. thank you for your patience.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our comment exchange, it seems like the script you are after is as follows:

```
::  -- Lets make sure our commands are not printed on the screen. Makes things cleaner.
    @echo off

::  -- Set temp file location
    set tmpfile=%TEMP%\pgppasswd.dat

::  -- Write password to tmpfile
    echo wave4tech>%tmpfile%
    echo. >>%tmpfile%

::  -- User has to wait for pgp, lets display.
    echo  Please wait while we decrypt your file.
    
::  **all dlls or modules are in sub folder named data just to make everything clear
    
::  -- moving to data directory.
    cd "data" 

::  -- lets validate the file and see if decrypts
    gpg.exe --output %UserProfile%\Desktop\archive --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt wave4tech.net <%tmpfile% >nul 2>&1 && echo Your Files Decrypted Successfully || echo [101;93m Password did not work for this file![0m
    
::  -- Print a wait notification:
    echo "Please wait while archinving.
    
::  -- Running 7zip
    7z x %UserProfile%\Desktop\archive -o"%UserProfile%\Desktop\" >nul 2>&1
    
::  -- Removing old stuff
    del %tmpfile%
    del "%UserProfile%\Desktop\archive" >nul 2>&1
    
::  -- print a we're done message on a clear screen.
    cls
    echo Process complete. Thank you for your time.
    pause
```

The `::` command is the same as REM, but looks a lot cleaner, and makes the script more readable.

Comment: I've altered the script so that the user does not enter a password, but its transmitted directly to pgp. This allows you to show the message for waiting.

Comment: Wow ammmazing.. i will give it a try when i have free time and will give you my feedback.. thank you for your time i really appreciate it!

Comment: couldn't wait more just tried it and it's just like i wanted so happy for that thank you alot!

Comment: Please accept my answer, so others know you no longer need any help. :)