# Adding execution time and progress bar to the desired number of executables on Windows running via a batch script

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch-file

This is a follow-up question of my [previous](https://superuser.com/questions/1726059/running-desired-number-of-executables-on-windows-using-batch-script/1726106?noredirect=1#comment2667259_1726106) question. Many thanks to @iTwasnTme, the following script (`my_loop_exe.bat`) runs desired number of executables (EXE) on my Windows 10 PC (x64, 8 CPUs).

```
@echo off & setlocal

for /d /r %%i in (*)do if exist "%%~i\run_jobs.bat" call %:^) "%%~dpnxi" "run_jobs.bat"

endlocal && goto :eof

%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" (set "_path=%~1" && set "_bat=%~2")
for /f %%i in ('wmic process where "name like '%%cmd.exe%%'" get commandline ^| findstr /c:"%_bat%" ^| find /v /c ""
    ')do if %%~i leq 6 (start "" /b /d "%_path%" %comspec% /s /c "%_path%\%_bat%") else >nul (timeout 10 & goto %:^))
```

Given 20 directories, I have been trying to add execution time and progress bar to the above script. I found several suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-a-command-on-the-windows-command-line), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108380/coding-a-real-time-progress-bar-in-batch), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1720645/real-time-progress-bar-on-windows-batch). I tried using `timecmd.bat` approach, added it to the OS path, and used it with the above script, as suggested in the first web link.

```
timecmd.bat my_loop_exe.bat
```

It didn't work as expected. The time is shown only at the beginning. This is **probably** because, the above `my_loop_exe.bat` batch script doesn't automatically return to the CMD once EXEs in all the directories have been executed. I need to hit `ENTER` then it returns.

I also tried:

```
echo %time%
my_loop_exe.bat
echo %time%
```

as a separate `.bat` file and ran it via CMD. It printed time two times at the beginning of the script, and then the same behavior, the above loop batch script runs, but doesn't return to the console once done processing all the directories (*I don't understand why*).

How do I add execution time to the above script such that it shows script's start time, end time and the total execution time and the progress bar (infinite progress bar, as @iTwasnTme made me realize adding % progress bar may not be accurate)?

Comment: you need to emit the time *in the loop*

Comment: You 2nd time need ! `!time!` and you probably do not need to do this using 2 bats files...

Comment: I was doing using two bat files to execute all the commands at the same time. Otherwise, i would need to execute three commands. In any case, the loop does not return automatically to the console so probably adding second time doesn't work anyways.

Comment: For a progress bar, see https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/how-to-add-progress-bar-to-bat-file.37130/ . It might be more useful than time, which is approximate; you could increment (or *decrement!*) the bar for each file moved.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check.